# Laravel blade checkbox creating curly braces

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, checkbox, laravel-blade

I'm using a super simple checkbox form in Laravel 5.3:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    @foreach($sorts as $sort)
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                {{!! Form::checkbox('agree', 'yes', array($sort => 'Country')) !!}} {{ $sort->Region }}
            </label>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@stop
```

It's printing the checkbox with this:

> {} Africa - North Africa

What's up with those curly braces?

I'm trying to grab data from the database, and for each line print the `$Region`. Which is working. But the available documentation and explanations for checkboxes in Laravel make no mention of this. What am I missing?

This is the controller btw:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;

class SortController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $sorts = DB::table('list_countries')->get();
        return view('Sort', compact('sorts'));
    }
}
```

And this is the Route:

```
Route::get('Sort', 'SortController@index');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct your braces

This is wrong

```
{{!! Form::checkbox('agree', 'yes', array($sort => 'Country')) !!}}
```

This is correct

```
{!! Form::checkbox('agree', 'yes', array($sort => 'Country')) !!}
```

Laravel [Documention](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#displaying-data)

Comment: Oh! You got it in one! Thanks. This wasn't mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`{{!! ... !!}}`

use

`{!! .. !!}`